# Spark Performance EMR(2.4.5) vs EKS(3.0.0)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, amazon-eks

I am running experiments with some Spark jobs and I am trying to compare performance on EMR and on EKS. The hardware that I used was 2 instances of m5.2xlarge (8 vCore, 32 GiB memory). The reason is that it is commonly shared hardware instances between EKS and EMR and therefore more reliable to compare performance.

I also shared the spark configuration:

```
--conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=3 \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=16 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=4g \
--conf spark.driver.memory=4g \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4g
```

(Spark 2.4.5 for EMR, Spark 3.0.0 for Kubernetes)

The spark jobs read some json files from S3 and they store parquet on S3 again.
I systematically get faster writes and reads from S3 on EMR (23% faster approximately on EMR).

Could that be because of s3-specific optimizations on EMR ? What could be possible things to do to make the performance better on Kubernetes ?

Comment: EMR(newer versions) default committer is EMR s3Optimized committers not FileOutputCommitter or S3OutputCommitter... they have optimized s3 communication from EMR. check this thread --> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/improve-apache-spark-write-performance-on-apache-parquet-formats-with-the-emrfs-s3-optimized-committer/

Comment: rename is the costliest operation when using object stores(like s3).. they kind of optimized that operations by bringing the concept of multi-part upload of a single file. imaging 10 thread upload a single file in chunks and 1 thread upload whole data ... basically the first one is much faster than the 2nd..

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the performance improvement on EMR is due to EMRFS which comes default with EMR while it doesn't come with EKS.